# Xcode 7.2 : Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm getting this error while trying to build my App. I'm lerning Swift (Beginner). I'm using Xcode 7.2.

This is where the Error appear.

```
    struct ParseCSV {

func parseURL (contentsOfURL: NSURL, encoding: NSStringEncoding) -> ([String])? {

    let columnDelimiter = ";"

    var nameOfSensors:[String]?

    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfURL: contentsOfURL, encoding: encoding)
        print(content)

        nameOfSensors = []

        let columns:[String] = content.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()) as [String]


        for column in columns {
            var values:[String] = []


            values = column.componentsSeparatedByString(columnDelimiter)

            let nameOfSensor = (name: values[0])

            nameOfSensors?.append(nameOfSensor)

        }

    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }

    return nameOfSensors      
   }       
}
```

Error

```
    1.  While emitting IR SIL function @_TFV18ConnectionVersuch28ParseCVS8parseURLfS0_FTCSo5NSURL8encodingSu_GSqGSaSS__ for 'parseURL' at /Users/lstudent/Documents/my_Apps/ConnectionVersuch2/ParseCSV.swift:16:5
```

I'm not importing any custom framework, so I don't know what or where could it be.

Comment: Which line do you get your error at?

Comment: I just upgrade my question. thank you

Comment: Just to make sure: It crashes while building (compiling, linking) the app? If so, try to restart XCode, reboot the Mac or even reinstall XCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs in this line

```
let nameOfSensor = (name: values[0])
```

which is just meaningless syntax. it's

```
let nameOfSensor = values[0]
```

But you can simplify the repeat loop

```
for column in columns {
   let values = column.componentsSeparatedByString(columnDelimiter)
   if let nameOfSensor = values.first {
      nameOfSensors?.append(nameOfSensor)
    }    
}
```

It checks also if the separated array contains a first item at all.

Comment: It's just wrong syntax. An array is a collection type which can be accessed by index. The `name:` parameter makes no sense at all, since the variable `nameOfSensor` is supposed to contain only a string.